# How to Close an open email using Applescript

Tags: applescript

I've been able to achieve 95% success using the following script on my Mac OS X 10.10.1  However, I can't get the email that I've opened to "Close".  Any suggestions???

Here's the Applescript:

```
using terms from application "Mail"
on perform mail action with messages theMessages for rule theRule
    tell application "Mail"

        -- walk through all matching messages
        repeat with thisMessage in theMessages
            -- open the message
            set openedMail to open thisMessage

            -- perform your UI scripting
            tell application "System Events"
                tell process "Mail"
                    -- Select the Print menu item
                    click (first menu item of menu "File" of menu bar 1 whose name begins with "Print")
                    tell window 1
                        -- Wait until the print sheet appears
                        repeat 30 times
                            if sheet 1 exists then exit repeat
                            delay 0.5
                        end repeat
                        tell sheet 1
                            -- Click the PDF button
                            click menu button "PDF"
                            -- Select the PDF to SBS Dropbox menu item
                            delay 0.5
                            click (first menu item of menu 1 of menu button "PDF" whose name begins with "PDF to SBS Dropbox")
                            delay 4
                        end tell
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell

            -- close the message
            close openedMail

        end repeat
    end tell
end perform mail action with messages
```

end using terms from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code doesn't work then why not try the same technique you used earlier with system events...

```
click (first menu item of menu "File" of menu bar 1 whose name begins with "Close")
```

Or you can just tell mail to do it with...

```
close window 1
```

Comment: Follow Up:  Both suggestions "worked".  Thanks.. However, I discovered my underlying problem to be the large file size (2-3mb) of the email that was being "saved as a PDF" and uploaded to the Cloud.  I needed to add a sufficient "delay" for the upload process to complete before closing the email.  Changing the delay from 4 to 20, plus adding in the suggestions to Close, and my program is working perfectly.  Thanks...